# Is there any way to simplify sum $\frac{1}{ (n - 2m)! m!}$?

Tags: factorial

I'm solving the following formula.

$\sum_{0 \le m \le n/2} \frac{1}{(n-2m)! m!}$

For me it is never simplified further. Is there anyone to give me an hint?

**I tried** :

Let $r = 2m$.

$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{0 \le m \le n/2} \frac{1}{(n-2m)! m!} &= \sum_{0 \le r \le n} \frac{n!}{(n-r)! (r/2)!} \frac{1}{n!} \\[10pt]
&= \sum_{0 \le r \le n} \frac{n!(r/2)!}{(n-r)! (r/2)!(r/2)!} \frac{1}{n!} \\[10pt]
&= \sum_{0 \le r \le n} \frac{n!(r/2)! 2^r}{(n-r)! r!} \frac{1}{n!}\\[10pt]
&= \sum_{0 \le r \le n} \binom{n}{r} (r/2)! 2^r \frac{1}{n!}\\[10pt]
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Do you have reason to believe that there's a closed form, or are you just hoping there might be one?

Comment: It has a nice exponential generating function $e^{x(x+1)}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like it doesn't have a closed form. The sequence

$$a_n=\sum_{0\leq m\leq n/2} \frac{n!}{(n-2m)!m!}$$

exists on OEIS [here](https://oeis.org/A047974), which lists come interesting properties, but gives no closed form, as well as the recurrence relation

$$a_n=a_{n-1}+2(n-1)a_{n-2}.$$